# Linux Kernel Scheduler: preemption

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduling

I have a piece of code that loop forever e.g it never enters kernel code. I use a tool to show the CPU utilization of all cores, it shows the first core has 100% utilization. But when I ssh into that server, the first core is no longer 100% used but the fourth core. As I know, if a task never enters the kernel, there is no way for kernel to stop that task or move that task to another core.